# Automating Angular 2 with Gulp in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: angular, visual-studio-2015, gulp

First of all, I am very new to Angular 2 and my main background is C#, ASP.Net, Core and Visual Studios.

I am trying to develop my first Angular2 application in VS2015 by watching some tutorials, videos.  I managed to follow the steps and made it run successfully.  But I am really confused that different people use different ways to achieve the same thing.

For example:

- Some put TS files in wwwroot, some put outside of wwwroot.  Some said
  we shouldn't put it in wwwroot.
- Some use Gulp to copy files to wwwroot.  Some use WebPack and combine all files in single big .js file?

So, I decided to develop the sample application with the following features

- TS Files will be outside of wwwroot and generated js & html files will be copied to wwwroot by using Gulp
- Want to automatically copy html files whenever I change
- Want to automatically copy js files whenever I change TS file

[image]

My gulpfile.js is like the following:

```
"use strict";

var gulp = require("gulp");
var del = require('del');

var scriptsSource = "./app/";
var scriptsDest = "./wwwroot/app";

gulp.task('clean', function () {
    return del([
        scriptsDest
    ]);
});

gulp.task("js", function () {
    gulp.src(scriptsSource + "**/*.js")
        .pipe(gulp.dest(scriptsDest));
});

gulp.task("html", function () {
    gulp.src(scriptsSource + "**/*.html")
        .pipe(gulp.dest(scriptsDest));
});

gulp.task("watch", function () {
    gulp.watch(scriptsSource + "**/*.html", ["html"]);
    gulp.watch(scriptsSource + "**/*.js", ["js"]);
});

gulp.task("copy-deps", ['clean','html', 'js']);
```

For html files, it copies them automatically whenever it has been changed.

But when I change the .ts file, it doesn't copy the .js files.  And I found out that .js file is not automatically generated when I change .ts file.  The new .js file is generated only when I re-build the VisualStudio Project.

my first question is... is it supposed to be like that?  Does it solely depend on VS build command?  Some programmers are not using VS as their IDE.  How do they generate .js files from .ts files?

[image]

The main problem is that my gulp-watch task didn't copy the new generated files.  It only copies the file which already exists (which does not depend on typescript files).  It completely ignores the newly generated file.  I have to run two tasks (clear & copy-des) again whenever I have changed ts file.

Could you please guide me how can I achieve the above requirments in VS2015?  If I am not going in the right direction, please feel free to suggest me.

I prefer to do the right way from the beginning rather than solving the problems which occur coz of the bad practice.  Thanks all.

***EDITED***
If you want to copy the artifacts (ts or html) after the build, you can configure those tasks in Task Runner Explorer.
[image]

Comment: Any reason why you're not using a seed or angular-cli?

Comment: Not particular reason.  When I searched in Google with Angular 2 in VS2015, I didn't see those 2 (seed & angular-cli).

Comment: I prefer to use `angular-cli` for preparing the project form me. As well as 90% people I know :) You should definitely try it.

Comment: `How do they generate .js files from .ts files?` Er, by compiling them using the Typescript compiler called `tsc`. There are plugins to call tsc from a gulp script. The idea is: watch ts, if ts changes run tsc on them, then put the result into the desired directory.